# c style string and dynamic allocation in c++

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array

I must implement a bunch of methods that allocates, modify and free a 2D array of c-style string. I cannot use string nor vectors nor any stl container.

getNewMat :

```
char*** getNewMat(int w, int h){
    char*** newMat = new char**[h];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < h ; i++){
        newMat[i] = new char*[w];
        for(int j = 0 ; j < w ; j++)
            newMat[i][j] = NULL;
    }
    return newMat;
}
```

fillMat

```
void fillMat(char***mat, int x, int y, char* newEl){
    mat[y][x] = newEl; //this will produce a segfault (even with good index)
}
```

showMat :

```
void showMat(char*** mat, int w, int h){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < h ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j  < w ; j++)
            cout << mat[i][j];  
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

so, can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: In `showMat`, you use `h` as limit for both loops. The `j` loop should use `w`.

Comment: The better solution, I can see here: you should implement your own class `string` and use it instead of `char*`.

Comment: That's a possibility, but anyway i'd like to know why this couldn't work, for comprehension itself (plus i fear this show a lack in understanding basic mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

In your `fillMat` method you do this:

```
mat[y][x] = newEl;
```

Where `x` and `y` are the dimensions of the two ranks of the array. That line will cause a segmentation fault because you're going outside the bounds of the array. `mat` is indexed from 0 to `length - 1` and setting by `x` and `y` is going 1 outside the bounds of the array.

Maybe you meant to loop through and set them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
{
     for (int k = 0; k < x; ++k)
         mat[i][k] = newEl;
}
```

Moreover, inside your `showMat` function you have this:

```
cout << showMat[i][j];
```

I think you meant for that to be `mat`:

```
cout << mat[i][j];
```

Comment: x, y are not the width and height of mat, but indexes at which the assignation is made, this line produce a segfault even with x, y = 0, 0

Comment: i didn't meant to loop or anything but simply to assign a value, but you're right for the cout, i'll edit my code

Answer (score 0):

1. `newMat[i][j] = NULL` - it's a bad idea. In `showMat` you will try to dereference a NULL pointer - this is UB and may cause a segfault.
2. `char*` - it's not a string - it's just a pointer to char, that *may* points to memory location, where can be beginning of string. If you want to work with it like with a string, you should allocate memory for it too.
3. `mat[y][x] = newEl` - it's a bad idea too. As I already said, `char*` is not a string, so, you can't just use assignment operator to copy data from one `C-string` into another. You should use `std::copy` or `std::strncpy`.
4. Do not forget to free allocated memory after using.

You should implement your own `string` class - it's the better solution, I can see there. At least, because it simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: `char *x = something;` x could contain a string, and so could y: `unsigned int y = something;`. I think you meant to say "It's not a string. It could point to a string, but it doesn't (because you're setting it to `NULL`)."

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, I mean, _x may point to memory location, where can be beginning of string. But it's still a pointer. Not a string._ Is it what you're asking about, or I'm missed something?

Comment: That sounds better. `char *x; strncpy((char *) &x, "", sizeof x);` x *might* contain a string, but it's highly unlikely to point to one.

Answer (score 0):

> I must implement a bunch of methods that allocates, modify and free a
>   2D array of c-style string. ...*snip*... so, can anyone please tell me
>   what's wrong with this?

A "c-style string" isn't a type. It's a representation of data within a type. `'\0'`-terminated strings are typically stored within `char` arrays, but you could store one just as easily in a `unsigned int` array. For example:

```
unsigned int message[32] = { 0 };
strcpy((char *) message, "Hello, world!");
printf("%s\n", (char *) message);
```

I discourage programming like this, however micro-optimistic the benefits may seem. It's also possible to store a string in something that *isn't* an array. Consider that a `char` might be suitable for storing an empty string:

```
char x = '\0';
printf("%s\n", &x);
```

It's reasonable to assume that you meant "an array of array of array of `char`", when you said "2D array of c-style string". Let us carry on in that direction.

---

I don't know a lot about C++, but there's a list of property of arrays which you probably haven't thought about in your quest to mimic *actual arrays*. I'll summarise these using `assert`ions:

```
#define x 7
#define y 13
#define z 1
char foo[x][y][z] = { 0 };
assert((char *) foo == foo[0]);
assert(sizeof foo == (char *) &foo[1] - (char *) &foo[0]);
assert(sizeof foo == x * y * z);
```

I'm not sure if you'll be able to solve your problem with any of these `assert`ions passing in C++, but I'm open for any input from others as to hints as to how one might...

Arrays are contiguous. This means that `newMat[x] + w` and `newMat[x+1]`, for values of x in `0 .. h-1`. In your code, this isn't a reality, because you allocate `newMat[x]` and `newMat[x+1]` separately. Similarly, it is expected that `newMay[0][y] == newMat[0][y+1] + n`, where `n` is the maximum length of your *strings*. This can be a problem when using generic array sorting algorithms, because they might rely upon your *arrays* being contiguous.

The closest you might come to solving this problem seems to involve allocating only once per dimension, rather than `h` times for the first dimension and `w` for the second. This would look something like this:

```
char ***getNewMat(size_t w, size_t h, size_t n){
    char ***newMat = new char **[h];
    newMat[0] = new char *[h*w];
    newMat[0][0] = new char[h*w*n];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < h; i++){
        newMat[i] = newMat[0] + i * w;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            newMat[i][j] = newMat[0][0] + i * w * n + j * n;
        }
    }

    return newMat;
}
```

---

One side-effect of arrays being contiguous is that you can't *assign* C-style strings by merely changing the pointer within the array to point to a different location. The pointer is the result of a conversion from an *array expression* to a *pointer expression* which isn't an lvalue. As I said earlier, I don't know much about C++, but in C that means the following code can't compile:

```
char foo[x][y][z] = { 0 };
foo[a][b] = "hello";
```

However, the following code *can* compile:

```
char *foo[x][y] = { 0 };
foo[a][b] = "hello";
```

The former might constitute an array of C-style strings, but the latter can't because of the contiguity rule we've covered, and the fact that it starts off with most if it's elements pointing to `NULL`, a pointer which can't point to *anything* let alone strings. There might be some operator overloading magic you can perform to permit the former to compile. I'm also open for any hints in the right direction to provide an example for the OP, here.